# Why "java -version" is not changing? on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, version-control, java-home

I am running below command to see available versions.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

and the result is: (I have deleted java8 folder from VirtualMachines directory)

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    11.0.13, x86_64:    "Amazon Corretto 11"    /Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-11.0.13/Contents/Home
    11.0.13, x86_64:    "OpenJDK 11.0.13"   /Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/semeru-11.0.13/Contents/Home
```

And I am entering

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/semeru-11.0.13/Contents/Home
```

or

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`
```

I am restarting termina but still when I enter `java -version`
the result is

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_312"
```

I do not remember whether I have installed them via site or homebrew but now i cannot change it. How can i achieve it ?

Comment: If your restart the terminal all the manual exports you do are lost unless they are written in some file that is sourced during terminal startup.

Comment: Also, running executables in the terminal will use the PATH variable, not JAVA_HOME.